# Ubuntu 14.04 single install not booting Mac Pro 4.1

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation, mac

So this is what has happened so far...

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 Mac version and now the Intel version on my Mac Pro 4.1.
Installation succeeded each time yet when I restart the computer it does not find any OS or Live USB.  Pressing Alt on startup shows me the live USB and nothing else.

So what can I do now?

Comment: is the name of the SSD really normal( 454532ae-cf65-457877e-8941 )? And is it normal to have an empty "boot" folder?

Comment: Same here... Ubuntu 14.04 is the first linux distro where this has happened.